# Getting 403 error while using axios in nodejs but working fine in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, cors

Below is the code snippet from Postman request, have used exactly the same headers mentioned in my controller file:

```
const axios = require('axios');
let data = JSON.stringify({
  "variables": {
    "context": {
      "siteId": 9001001,
      "locale": "en_US",
      "eapid": 1,
      "currency": "USD",
      "device": {
        "type": "DESKTOP"
      },
      "identity": {
        "duaid": "65cbd87c-ebb5-ab83-a4c1-812db78bb787",
        "expUserId": "-1",
        "tuid": "-1",
        "authState": "ANONYMOUS"
      },
      "privacyTrackingState": "CAN_TRACK",
      "debugContext": {
        "abacusOverrides": []
      }
    },
    "criteria": {
      "primary": {
        "dateRange": {
          "checkInDate": {
            "day": 1,
            "month": 3,
            "year": 2024
          },
          "checkOutDate": {
            "day": 5,
            "month": 3,
            "year": 2024
          }
        },
        "destination": {
          "regionName": "73 W Monroe St, Chicago, IL 60603, USA",
          "regionId": null,
          "coordinates": null,
          "pinnedPropertyId": null,
          "propertyIds": null,
          "mapBounds": null
        },
        "rooms": [
          {
            "adults": 2,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "secondary": {
        "counts": [
          {
            "id": "resultsStartingIndex",
            "value": 150
          },
          {
            "id": "resultsSize",
            "value": 50
          }
        ],
        "booleans": [],
        "selections": [
          {
            "id": "sort",
            "value": "RECOMMENDED"
          },
          {
            "id": "privacyTrackingState",
            "value": "CAN_TRACK"
          },
          {
            "id": "useRewards",
            "value": "SHOP_WITHOUT_POINTS"
          },
          {
            "id": "searchId",
            "value": "d1342ebe-2e4c-4c8d-8838-a3967204a6f2"
          }
        ],
        "ranges": []
      }
    },
    "destination": {
      "regionName": null,
      "regionId": null,
      "coordinates": null,
      "pinnedPropertyId": null,
      "propertyIds": null,
      "mapBounds": null
    },
    "shoppingContext": {
      "multiItem": null
    },
    "returnPropertyType": false,
    "includeDynamicMap": true
  },
  "operationName": "LodgingPwaPropertySearch",
  "extensions": {
    "persistedQuery": {
      "sha256Hash": "e4ffcd90dd44f01455f9ddd89228915a177f9ec674f0df0db442ea1b20f551c3",
      "version": 1
    }
  }
});

let config = {
  method: 'post',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'https://www.vrbo.com/graphql',
  headers: { 
    'authority': 'www.vrbo.com', 
    'accept': '*/*', 
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,no;q=0.7,de;q=0.6', 
    'cache-control': 'no-cache', 
    'client-info': 'shopping-pwa,unknown,unknown', 
    'content-type': 'application/json', 
    'origin': 'https://www.vrbo.com', 
    'pragma': 'no-cache', 
    'referer': 'https://www.vrbo.com/search?adults=2&amenities=&children=&d1=2023-12-27&d2=2023-12-28&destination=73%20W%20Monroe%20St%2C%20Chicago%2C%20IL%2060603%2C%20USA&endDate=2024-03-05&latLong=&mapBounds=&pwaDialog=&regionId&semdtl=&sort=RECOMMENDED&startDate=2024-03-01&theme=&userIntent=', 
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"', 
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0', 
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"', 
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty', 
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors', 
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin', 
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 
    'x-enable-apq': 'true', 
    'x-page-id': 'page.Hotel-Search,H,20', 
    'Cookie': 'DUAID=34038852-eeed-3ff7-2794-3f3ad7416658; HMS=97cbb6af-4a5b-4c92-8434-f774fe399b3e; MC1=GUID=34038852eeed3ff727943f3ad7416658; ak_bmsc=F7207E4831989D8F8CBC63B4B2AC3EA8~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQU0o5F7H9ZTmOAQAAZw2GTReuS+CkEFW0D1q/7Q6cDG+39zqCoPS7yf1sWNttccmLjgToV/X6ji9QN6/hW7ceAfjrR5/3ok7RB/5cDjM1B8iEQ3ju2cDMLLRShRLwEYnKPo5jV5mJJmoi6vSAnS2npC4doEgSiAvmusElMwK0JkJLnbkWsswN4cgxh0zU/voSUOuxKC312N0xipTk9lLAxNlJEc1zactVqiu7zSjdCbtOwMwz+dBC8EtM/8e7Z0NtbwJzoLS2bL0pwYPKIUUkCqnIjHb8fALLYLP1lJBnPIMWIokkVlnpG96fWDOsGubv3stzkju3EEdxitd9X6QnFdHyibLqgrG/fEwxbjzTZE+F3+EAXv4=; bm_sv=CFFF6ECCB4FB11BFDAC3D5291BB3C6EE~YAAQMiEPF9WR5jiOAQAATJSoTRegEJDalBWUfUXb1tsmCTF6OIxpaAlPLhO6/xdxO7o4Y9xK4s+av9Qnf6u6k3Alw2GXDvgrnkF+MGtlWF/3CgIZpbvNWfv+1gnCtrVUAAupInH/zf22f/vPJtCJZ1PLXxNYvS6eL7bF8JfTrgWBPCn3s8e/bQZ+ToZdA6lRo5xGjAUizrzOP+IKtuvzQ8SMX3TOTYusCM1SRX+R52xniiEqnqYoBVeoXg/5Eg==~1; cesc=%7B%22marketingClick%22%3A%5B%22false%22%2C1710699877408%5D%2C%22hitNumber%22%3A%5B%221%22%2C1710699877408%5D%2C%22visitNumber%22%3A%5B%2211%22%2C1710699877408%5D%2C%22entryPage%22%3A%5B%22page.Hotel-Search%22%2C1710699877408%5D%7D; hav=34038852-eeed-3ff7-2794-3f3ad7416658; ha-device-id=34038852-eeed-3ff7-2794-3f3ad7416658; has=49264c24-90ba-a1bd-7c55-7b83abf65d84; hav=34038852-eeed-3ff7-2794-3f3ad7416658'
  },
  data : data
};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Below is how I'm using in controller file with other logic involved, even try enabling the cors option middleware from the documentation :

```
async function fetchListings(address, pageSize) {
    const url = process.env.API_URL; // API endpoint to fetch listings
    body.variables.criteria.secondary.counts[1].value = pageSize;
    body.variables.criteria.primary.destination.regionName = address;
    const requestBody = JSON.stringify(body);
    try {
        let response = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: headers,
            data: requestBody
        });
        console.log(response.data);
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Even have cors options in app.js file :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCuRW.png)

Expecting the fix for the same as I've been stuck on the same issue for a long time

Comment: Try using a request analysis tool such as https://webhook.site/ and send the request from Postman to the webhook URL and then again using Axios to examine the differences in request payloads to determine why one works and the other does not.

Comment: Instead of webhook I used the console for the request and the headers shown over there were exactly what I've used except the Postman token which changes with every request

Comment: Please provide screenshots of each request and their headers if you would like further help troubleshooting the issue. The only thing I can see from your code examples is that you may have forgotten to provide a value for the `headers` property in the `fetchListings` function.